# Combine two different DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I am trying to modify a DQL to combine two different results:

```
class ContentRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param string $userId
     * @return array
     */
    public function findOwnerReadByUserId(string $userId): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->select('c')
            ->innerJoin('c.reactions', 'rea', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('rea.content', 'c.id'))
            ->where('c.userId = :userId')
            ->orderBy('rea.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setParameters(['userId' => $userId]);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $userId
     * @return array
     */
    public function findOtherReadByUserId(string $userId): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->select('c')
            ->innerJoin('c.receivers', 'rec', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('rec.userId', ':userId'))
            ->innerJoin('c.reactions', 'rea', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('rea.content', 'c.id'))
            ->where('rec.read = :read')
            ->orderBy('rea.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setParameters(['userId' => $userId, 'read' => true]);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Both queries are working like a charm but I would like to avoid the array_merge because of the order by. Any suggestion to retrieve both results in one single DQL?

[SQLfiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f0e5/2)

Comment: Do you have any specific problem writing the single DQL?

Comment: @AlexBlex not really... functions as I exposed are in a standard class repository

Comment: @AlexBlex do you how to do it in a single query?

Comment: not really... the question is quite vague. I was wondering if you can narrow it down, but since you have no problems writing the query, you are more than welcome to self-answer the question.

Comment: @AlexBlex doctrine does not support UNION ALL and without it I don't know how to do it... I'm quite sure there is a better solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can achieve something similar with left joins. Could you prepare an sqlfiddle with essential data to make it a bit more clear of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AlexBlex question updated with the sqlfiddle

Comment: Sorry, but the sql provided made it even more confusing. Both queries have `INNER JOIN receiver` but your `findOwnerReadByUserId ` has no reference to `receiver`.  Could you add some *data* (the insert statement in the builder part) to ensure you get the expected result when you run the queries?

Comment: @AlexBlex the `findOwnerReadByUserId ` was wrong! The right one is the sql one

Comment: @AlexBlex link updated!

Comment: Fair enough, the latest revision of the fiddle shed some light =) Just to confirm you are happy with multiple identical `content` objects returned as a result of inner joins when you have multiple reactions and receivers linked to the same content?

Comment: I would like to have unique contents

Comment: Take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f0e5/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexBlex

this is the answer:

```
    /**
     * @param string $userId
     * @return array
     */
    public function findNotPendingByUserId(string $userId): array
    {
        $dql = <<<DQL
  SELECT DISTINCT c
  FROM ApiBundle:Content c
  INNER JOIN c.receivers rec 
  INNER JOIN c.reactions rea
  WHERE (rec.read = true AND (c.userId = :userId OR rec.userId = :userId))
  ORDER BY rea.createdAt DESC
DQL;

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameters(['userId' => $userId])
            ->getResult();
    }
```